Piping tar archive to host fails on docker run but works on docker exec
I'm trying to get some libraries out of a Docker image, since I temporarily need it in another environment.
Since I need symlinks to persist through this, I'm trying to tar the directory and pipe it to my hot system to immediately untar it there. In the end I want to pipe them directly into a running Kubernetes Pod.
Since I don't have any environment running with the image, that I need the files from, I tried to do the following:
docker run --rm bitnami/postgresql:11.22.0-debian-11-r4 \
    tar cf - -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu . | tar xf -

This results in
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
write /dev/stdout: broken pipe

But when I do this in an already running container it works.
Start a docker container with the image and open a bash (so it does not start the postgres service but stays alive):
docker run --rm -it --name my-postgresql bitnami/postgresql:11.22.0-debian-11-r4 -- bash

No open up a new terminal on your host and execute the following:
docker exec my-postgresql \
    tar cf - -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ . |\
    tar xf -

This works like a charm.
Can anyone explain to me, what I do wrong in the former example? Thanks in advance!

(I'm concerned about the higher-level use case.  It's common in Kubernetes to have multiple replicas of a Pod, and depending on your environment, it's possible for a Pod to be deleted and recreated outside your control, maybe if the cluster autoscaler deletes a Node.  What files exactly are these, and how will you actually use them in the Kubernetes environment?)

I only need the libs temporary. Postgres comes woth an upgrade command to do in-place upgrades from an old major version to a new. But for that I need the libraries and binaries from the old version available as well as the new ones. See here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html. I don't need them after the migration anymore.

For a scenario like that I might consider using a Dockerfile COPY --from command to copy the files into a new image.  Once you have it in an image, you can docker run it with appropriate Docker volumes and test it locally, and once you're sure the upgrade works, then you can run the identical image in a Kubernetes Job, without any manual setup.

I don't see too much of a benefit there to a good documentation how to do such an upgrade. It's not like it happens every day. But regular enough, that we want to have a process. Also I don't think I want to go through the hassle of building and publishing an image for that. Especially since we probably would never actually re-use them because the upgrades are from different versions.

Also, the data is in a PV. I would need to make sure to shutdown the DB Pod and then figure out how to attach the PV to the job. This will probably be a manual process again. But one that is less straight forward than "execute this to copy libraries to the container temporarily".

For (semi-)automatic updates we plan to look into CloudNativePG (https://cloudnative-pg.io/). But for the time being, we still need some way to do the upgrades manually.

The bitnami postgres image includes an ENTRYPOINT script:
$ docker image inspect bitnami/postgresql:11.22.0-debian-11-r4   -f '{{ .Config.Entrypoint }}'
[/opt/bitnami/scripts/postgresql/entrypoint.sh]

That script produces some output on stdout before tar produces any output; this results in data that can't be processed by the reading tar command. You can avoid that problem by replacing the entrypoint:
docker run --rm --entrypoint tar bitnami/postgresql:11.22.0-debian-11-r4 \
  cf - -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu . |
  tar xf -


The output of the entrypoint goes to stderr, I think. At least it is also printed, when I execute the script from my post. I think I tried your solution already and ran into an issue with tar. But I eill try again and post the results.

There is some output to stderr, yes, but if you examine the ENTRYPOINT script you'll see there is also some output on stdout, and that's the source of the problem.

Okay. I just looked through my history and saw, that I actually tested this, but forgot the trailing . of the tar command. That failed with "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive" and I assumed it somehow could not read the directory. Added the . and now it works lie a charm! Thanks!
